# ChromeDriver needs a Chrome installation?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

It throws the exception:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "topmenu-gtk-module"
Created new window in existing browser session.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
Timed out waiting for driver server to start.

Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'luis', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux',     os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-87-generic', java.version:     '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:193)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
```

I'm new to this, am I missing something? Should be any other server running in my host?

Comment: What is your chrome version and os? can you hit 'chrome://version'

Comment: Yes, it shows: 

Google Chrome 55.0.2883.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Revision 451c239c3b0722dc867b0f75839b959f729b756a-refs/branch-heads/2883@{#698}
OS Linux 
JavaScript V8 5.5.372.29
Flash 26.0.0.137
User Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36
Command Line /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --flag-switches-begin --enable-devtools-experiments --flag-switches-end
Executable Path /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

Comment: Can you update it to chrome 59 and check with the same code\?

Comment: Issue remains. I have updated to: oogle Chrome 60.0.3112.78 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Revision f901216ec1e383df23283fec9bc8f4e8b67aa0fb-refs/branch-heads/3112@{#671}
OS Linux
JavaScript V8 6.0.286.44
Flash 26.0.0.137 /home/luis/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/26.0.0.137/libpepflashplayer.so
User Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36
Command Line /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --flag-switches-begin --enable-devtools-experiments --flag-switches-end
Executable Path /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

Comment: Is the [downloaded chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) in your PATH environment variable? You need the path\chromedriver.exe in the path.

Comment: Headless chrome has to work in v59 for linux. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome. Kindly check again

Comment: The problem was that I was pointing to Chrome installation, not to Chrome driver path. @MikeJRamsey56 was right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you want to use chrome then you need to download it's binary from below URL :-

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Now add `System.setProperty`before driver instance

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Workspace\\JmeterWebdriverProject\\src\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Nowif you want to use headless then use phantomjs. It is a stable build with you can use for your headleass jobs. donwload it from below link :-

http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Now add `System.setProperty`before driver instance

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true); // not really needed: JS enabled by default
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "C:/phantomjs.exe");
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

refer the link below for more info :-

http://seleniumworks.blogspot.in/2013/03/headless-browser-testing-using.html

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Hi, I'm migrating from PhantomJS to headless Chrome because PhantomJS is poor maintained and javascript from Facebook is not running anymore (throws lot of errors and pages are not well rendered). I have already set the system property "webdriver.chrome.driver", but it won't start.

Comment: I have solved it. The problem was that I was pointing to Chrome installation, not to Chrome driver path. Thanks! Marked as accepted.